# Accessing 'Calendar' field types with the channel:entries tag

Tags: channel-entries, solspace, solspace-calendar, entries, date

I'm trying to make an all-in-one feed for the home page of a site that would pull together all the latest entries (whether they be blog posts, events etc.)

So I've got a entries loop that goes like so:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="posts|calendar_events"
    sticky="no"
    status="open|featured"
    limit="10"
    disable="categories|member_data|category_fields"
}
```

calendar_events being the channel created by the Solspace Calendar add-on. The channel field with of Calendar type is called event_time. I want to know if there was a way to display the event start times **and end times** through the entries tag using my `event_time` variable.

When I just put `{event_time}` it displays the Calendar ID. I'd rather not be embedding a template for every event that appears but I suppose I could use the event_time and/or entry_id to display the time via embed variables.

Any help would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calendar data can only be pulled from Calendar tags. The Calendar widget custom field does not output any useful data (unless you need the calendar ID) if directly used in `{exp:channel:entries}` like a regular field variable (eg. {event_time}).

You could pass the `{entry_id}` from `{exp:channel:entries}` into the `event_id=""` parameter of a Calendar tag, such as `{exp:calendar:cal}` or `{exp:calendar:events}`. Quick example (you might need to tweak for your own situation):

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="posts|calendar_events"
    sticky="no"
    status="open|featured"
    limit="10"
    disable="categories|member_data|category_fields"
}

   {if channel_name == "calendar_events"}
      {exp:calendar:events event_id="{entry_id}"}
         Very first start date: {event_first_date format="%Y.%m.%d"}
         Very last end date: {event_last_date format="%Y.%m.%d"}
      {/exp:calendar:events}
   {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```